# Flex Box Two Columns with Header

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am a **beginner** with coding, and just trying to create random layouts to better my skills. I am having trouble with my flex boxes for this one. I also attached a photo below of my sketch for reference!

I literally do not know how I can't manage to get this, because I know flexboxes are fairly simple.

Can someone help set me on the right track?

```css
.body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.both-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /* margin: 10px; */
}

.top-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.column-left {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: black solid 1px;
  /* padding: 10px; */
}

.column-right {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: black solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  /* padding: 10px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="both-column">
  <div class="top-column">
    <marquee>welcome to my portolfio if you have any questions please reach out!</marquee>
  </div>
  <div class="column-left">
    <h1>ARTIST NAME</h1>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="google.com">instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">are.na</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">github</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">email</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="column-right">
    <ol>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: sketch of desired layout]

I tried to arrange my flexboxes, but I am having trouble getting the header marquee part above the rest... I am not sure if the grid would be better for this or if I need to use a z-index. This is probably a fairly easy flexbox question for many!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex-wrap: wrap`. also `box-sizing: border-box`:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.both-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /* margin: 10px; */
}

.top-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.column-left {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: black solid 1px;
  /* padding: 10px; */
}

.column-right {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: black solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  /* padding: 10px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="both-column">
  <div class="top-column">
    <marquee>welcome to my portolfio if you have any questions please reach out!</marquee>
  </div>
  <div class="column-left">
    <h1>ARTIST NAME</h1>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="google.com">instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">are.na</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">github</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">email</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="column-right">
    <ol>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
      <li><a href="google.com">PROJECT ONE</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```